# Limit each occurrence of a list by 1

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have the following query that prints out a list of numbers. I would like to limit each unique number by 1.

For example, if there is three 18 in the database, it will print out 18, 18, 18, and if they are two occurrences of 5, it will print out 5,5. I only it to appear 18, and 5 in this case.

```
let sqlSelectBoxInformation = "SELECT longestDimension from box ";

connectionBoxInformation.query(sqlSelectBoxInformation, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        // Check to see if the user entered hashtag is found in the database
        // Create a variable to track if the item was found
        var data = {
            rows: rows,
            userHashtag: databaseHashtag
        }
        res.render('delivery/chooseBox', data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT longestDimension from box
```

or `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT longestDimension from box GROUP BY longestDimension
```

Comment: Minus 1 for the second suggestion, but +1 for the first

Comment: Thanks for. How would set up an if condition such that if no result is return, it will render an error page pretty much If(true) { ...} else {}

Comment: you know that ur sql is supposed to return some type of result, if the result set is null then that will be ur else{}

Answer (score 1):

Please note also `DISTINCT` always applies to all columns returned. Putting parentheses around one column makes no difference in its behavior.

If you want your results to contain only unique values of `longestDimension` when dealing with `subquery` or multiple columns, you can use a `GROUP BY` clause instead - but then you have to decide some rules for which values you want to return in the other columns. You do this by using aggregate functions like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, etc.

Simplified example:

```
SELECT  SG.SGID,
    MIN(SG.START_TIME),              --the lowest start time for this sgid.
    COUNT(DISTINCT en.EnrollmentID)  --the unique enrollments for this sgid.
FROM StudentGroups SG 
INNER JOIN Enrollments EN ON SG.SGID = EN.SGID
GROUP BY SG.SGID;
```

(For context `SG` here stands for `StudentGroup`.) When joining multiple tables as in your original query, you have to be careful when counting and summing things, as duplicates from the join can give you incorrect results.

Another option would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to return one row for each `SGID`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  SG.SGID,
        SG.START_TIME, 
        en.EnrollmentID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SGID ORDER BY SG.START_TIME) as RN
    FROM StudentGroups SG 
    INNER JOIN Enrollments EN ON SG.SGID = EN.SGID
)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

This numbers the rows for each `SGID`, starting at 1 and sorted by the value of `SG.START_TIME`. It will return the one row with the earliest start time for each `SGID`. If multiple rows have the same start time, it will select any one of those, more or less at random. You could add more fields to the `ORDER BY` clause to further define which rows are returned.

Comment: Row number is not an option